Unpublish datasource items under Data folder in Sitecore SXA site
I am unpublishing item in Sitecore SXA. I have created an item with two rich text editor components.

I have added the second rich text editor component and selected the datasource item from data folder.

Data folder containing reusable data items.

When I am trying to unpublish the Page from the below option.

It unpublish the item in web database along with datasource item as well except the datasource item under Data folder.
Is it default behavior of Sitecore SXA?

When the item in sitecore is unpublished it unpublishes the datasource item under Data folder.
Once an item is unpublished its relevant data source is also unpublished

Not specific to SXA but Sitecore in general.
The publishing restrictions are not shared to referenced datasources, which would also cause issues, when an item is referenced from multiple pages.
The items in the local 'Data' folder on the other hand will be unpublished, because their parent is missing on the WEB database after you unpublish the page.
So the item stays published unless the item itself or one of its parents is restricted or unpublished.

By default, when you unpublish an item in Sitecore all the child items will also be unpublished since there would be no parent for the child item(in the web database) when the item is deleted. Its a functionality within Sitecore by default.
Therefore, when you unpublish the item, its local Data folder also gets unpublished from web database. Items under the Texts folder whether they are in the current site or the shared site, are not unpublished since they might be used in some other pages as well as it's a shared/global location.
Hope this helps!!!
